# Initializing an array of bools - returning null

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, boolean

I'm having a lot of problems initializing an array of bools. When using the `NSLog` i keep getting `(null)`. I'm trying to set up the mutable array `piecesInPlace` with 40 NO's. I've tried changing `setupArrayWithFalses` to `YES` for testing purposes, and still get `(null)`.

```
BOOL setupArrayWithFalses = NO;
for (int i=0; i<40; i++) {
    [piecesInPlace addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:setupArrayWithFalses]];
}
NSLog(@"Value of object: %@", [piecesInPlace objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you initializing you array?

```
piecesInPlace = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```